# Continuity of the spectrum under weaker notions of convergence

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $T:X\to X$ be a linear operator on a Banach space $X$. 
We know that the spectrum of $T$ is an upper semicontinuous 
function of $T$ for the uniform convergence: that is, if $T_n:X\to X$ is a sequence 
of operators, s.t, $T_n\to T$ uniformly then, given an open set $G$ containing
the spectrum of $T$, $\sigma(T)$, there must exist $k$ s.t  $n>k$  implies  that $\sigma (T_n)$ is contained in $G$.

I would like to know if this result remains valid under 
weaker conditions, like $T_n$ converges to $T$ in
the compact parts of $X$.

I'd like to know if properties like spectral gap in 
the spectrum remain if we  weaken the notion of
convergence.

Comment: Have a look at the paper of Keller and Liverani. They make an assumption that appears naturally in dynamical systems, and prove a continuity result for the spectrum exterior to the essential spectral radius.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Could you provide me  the name of the paper?

Comment: Stability of the spectrum for transfer operators